# How can I setup Data Sources in Cognos 10

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-bi

When I attempt to create a new package a new window opens in order to select the desired data source from the list.

The list is empty although I have succesfully defined and tested a datasource through Cognos Administration > Configuration > Data Sources Connections.

Which is the right way to create a new package and use a MS SQL as a datasource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I guess I had to create and publish a new package through the Framework Manager, that was running on a different server.